# Error Object Reference Not found when Record does not found using Linq to Entity my Query attached

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

i am trying to get one column value using linq to entity.

If record does not found it must be null.

my code is,

```
string SeqNum = Db.Visits
                    .Where(v => v.Status == 5 && v.BuildingId == 540)
                    .OrderByDescending(v => v.VisitNumber)
                    .Select(v => v.VisitNumber).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

I am getting error Object reference not fount because record does not exist for id 540 if i replace it with 7 it has record and does not occur any error.

Answer (score 0):

```
var SeqNum = Db.Visits
                .Where(v => v.Status == 5 && v.BuildingId == 540)
                .OrderByDescending(v => v.VisitNumber)
                .Select(v => v.VisitNumber).FirstOrDefault();
```

Remove .tostring() as the query returns the null value